# INVALID_MULTI_PART_REQUEST response when adding a document using a CompositeTemplate

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to add a PDF document to an existing draft envelope by using a CompositeTemplate so DocuSign can convert the PDF fields to tabs automatically for me.  Unfortunately the request fails with a HTTP code 400 and the following response:

```
{"errorCode":"INVALID_MULTI_PART_REQUEST","message":"An error was found while parsing the multipart request. No documents found in request."}
```

This error makes no sense to me since I am specifying the document by using the `documentBase64` property so it should not be using multipart.

I am calling `PUT .../accounts/???/envelopes/???/documents` with a body of:

```
{
  "compositeTemplates" : [ {
    "document" : {
      "documentBase64" : "...",
      "documentId" : "200",
      "name" : "document.pdf",
      "transformPdfFields" : "true"
    },
    "inlineTemplates" : [ {
      "recipients" : {
        "signers" : [ {
          "defaultRecipient" : "true",
          "email" : "jdoe@domain.test",
          "name" : "John Doe",
          "recipientId" : "1"
        } ]
      },
      "sequence" : "1"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Adding documents to the envelope works fine if I don't use a CompositeTemplate and just put the document directly in the `documents` attribute at the top level of the request JSON.  Unfortunately, responses to other questions in stackoverflow seem to indicate that `transformPdfFields` only works when the document is inside a CompositeTemplate (and indeed it didn't convert PDF fields to tabs when I tried it that way).

Comment: I'm not aware of the need to use compositeTemplate to use transformPdfFields. Did you try to do it w/o a template?

Comment: Why don't you create the envelope with the PDF and transformPdfFields to begin with?

Comment: I did try setting transformPdfFields directly on the document without using a template  but no tabs were actually added when looking in the envelope.  This was a while back on my first attempt to do this so it may be worth a shot to try it again.

Comment: We need to add documents to the envelope as they become available so we can't do this at envelope creation time.

Comment: I stand corrected, I tried again without using templates and it worked perfectly.  The last time I tried this was a few months back and the tabs were not being created.  Either I did something different in my code this time or there was an issue in the api at that time.  I was trying the template approach based on replies to an older question [Creating Template with Transformed PDF Form Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34213363)

Comment: I'll post this as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use a composite template for PDF Transform fields. If this was posted somewhere else in Stackoverflow - let me know and I'll correct it.

You can just set    `"transformPdfFields" : "true"`
at any envelope and it should work just fine.